# How to "restore" onchange event

Tags: javascript, onchange, reset

I have a textarea element, with onchange event assigned. The event function validates textarea value and in case there is a problem, it has to be fixed before the user can continue. I have problem with this scenario:

1) An user chnages the value
2) They click outside the textarea => onchanged is fired
3) Validation fails, so I display an alert and I call $("#element").focus() => the user is back for editing
4) In case they click outside the element now without any text modification, no onchange event is fired and that's the issue.

So I need to "reset" onchange status - somehow specify original value before I call $("#element").focus(). Is it possible to do it with JS or do I have to handle it myself with onblur event?

Comment: you could also try the event onblur for validation, which is triggered when the element loses focus

Comment: `onblur` event should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try onkeyup event instead of on change. you may need to change the validation a little though

Comment: sry, it doesn't make sense - it would mean the validation would be done any time the user presses a key .... so, when the user is "in middle of the change" the content would be always invalid as the change must be completed at first ...

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround may do it.

In onfocus handler, save the current value temporare, then set val to an empty string, then the value again.

```
$("#element").on("focus", function() {
  var val = $("#element").val();
  $("#element").val("");
  $("#element").val(val);
})

$("#element").focus()
```

Yeah, listening on `onblur` and validating is even a better solution, without hacks/workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

onblur event would solve your problem, since it is fired each time the element loses focus:

```
$('#elementID').blur(function()  {
    // validation
})
```